# Is this wiring between two USB-C connectors (receptacle) valid?

Tags: routing, usb-c

I am working on a small (hobby) device that does passthrough of USB-C connection (signals are untouched, only power/gnd are used in the device).

To simplify assembly I put both receptacles on the top side of PCB. But since there are too many differential pairs in this setup they are all crossed. However if I "simulate" upside-down connection (which is supported by USB-C connector), then all signal lines are simple straight lines! This means connecting RX1N to RX2N, TX2N to TX1N etc. (see schematic below)

So I wonder if this wiring is valid? Is there any possible issues with this (non-compliant cables aside)?

[image]

Comment: do you want to maintain superspeed operation through this link? If so, you have to consider a lot more than just whether the traces are straight or not.

Comment: @Hearth I am aware of high-frequency connection issues -- diff.pairs, gnd vias etc. My question is specifically about flipping the wiring.

Comment: I don't see any problem with that. It's identical to using an extension cable and flipping the connector on one end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is not that reversal is invalid, but that a USB C female to female coupler is invalid.

All but the most basic USB C cables (3A USB 2.0) rely on an electronic marker inside the cable to detect the capabilities and orientation of the cable. Coupling two cables together is not a supported configuration.

If it's for your own use only and you only need USB2 then you may able to get away with connecting all four CC pins together, then using basic passive cables. You should still be aware of the potential for up to 20V on Vbus.

Comment: Are you sure this is not TB3 you mean? As far as I understand USB-C cables have no active components in them and the orientation of the cable is achieved with CC1/CC2 pull-up on device side (and not in cable).

Comment: Ugh, just reading about it you are right, it is a mess, Probably I will just go with USB2.0 connection then, which is also super easy then. As for 20V, just checked this fits into my voltage regulator specs. It should be able to handle +-20V and produce usable 3.3.